# Attaching events to dynamic elements in wordpress - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to make a script that allows me to click on one div and that click triggers click on another. This another element is outside and nowhere near this first element. These elemnts i want to trigger click on are dynamically generated. Site runs on wordpress.

Here are elements im clicking on, just simple divs, eleven dives total:

```
<div id="jedna">
        </div>

<div id="dva">
        </div>

<div id="tri">
        </div>
```

etc..

Here are elemts i want to trigger click event on, these are generated:

```
<div class="swiper-slide" style="width: 356.6px;" data-slide-number="1" data-swiper-slide-index="1"></div>
<div class="swiper-slide" style="width: 356.6px;" data-slide-number="2" data-swiper-slide-index="2"></div>
<div class="swiper-slide" style="width: 356.6px;" data-slide-number="3" data-swiper-slide-index="3"></div>
<div class="swiper-slide" style="width: 356.6px;" data-slide-number="4" data-swiper-slide-index="4"></div>
```

I belive the only problem is that attaching events on these elements is not working even tho i attached it.

Here is full script, clicking function and attaching of events onto data-slide-number identifiers:

```
<script>
var $=jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).on('click', '#jedna', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="0"]').click(); 
});


$(document).on('click', '#dva', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="1"]').click(); 
});


$(document).on('click', '#tri', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="0"]').click(); 
});

$(document).on('click', '#styri', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="3"]').click(); 
});


$(document).on('click', '#pat', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="4"]').click(); 
});

$(document).on('click', '#sest', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="4"]').click(); 
});

$(document).on('click', '#sedem', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="6"]').click(); 
});

$(document).on('click', '#osem', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="7"]').click(); 
});

$(document).on('click', '#devat', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="8"]').click(); 
});

$(document).on('click', '#desat', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="9"]').click(); 
});


$(document).on('click', '#jedenast', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="10"]').click(); 
});

document.querySelectorAll('[data-slide-number]').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log(item.getAttribute("data-slide-number"));
  })
})
</script>
```

Any idea what am i missing ?

Here is website where you can check it out: http://www.sajdikyapartments.sk/
Its exactly in the middle, i want to click on building on image, that have hover efects on divs at top of them, and with that trigger clicking on tabs right above the image (01 Apartman, 02 Apartman etc..)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your dev console?

Comment: No, no errors, clicking is occouring but nothing is happening, i believe the only problem is with attaching events to **data-slide-number** elements. You can check website, i edited original question

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `.trigger( "click" );` (see JQuery documentation here https://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

So something like this maybe...

```
$(document).on('click', '#jedna', function() {
    $('*[data-slide-number="0"]').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Now i'm getting **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list** error in console

Comment: thnaks, no error now, but its still not working, i believe clicking function is fine but there is some problem with attaching event listener to **data-slide-number** but i have no idea where is the problem, since its attached as the last thing is script